# Postgres11 vacuum taking days

Tags: postgresql, postgres-11

I have set maintenance_work_mem 50GB and trying to run 200GB non partitioned table with 10 indexes manually. I am wondering it is taking 3 days still not completed vacuum.

I know, these many indexes bad but not understanding why vacuum not finished.

Note: No blockings observed

[image]

Comment: What does [pg_stat_progress_vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/progress-reporting.html) show?

Comment: 100% scan completed and then no change

Comment: That is your interpretation of what it shows.  What does it actually show?  As in, cut and paste the literal output (as formatted text).

Comment: Added image to confirm the status is same all the time

Comment: 25GB index scanning took 30 hours, By this time auto vacuum started and blocked by Manual vacuum that already running from 3 days